# Show that $f,g$ form basis for function space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\textbf{F}^{\{1,2\}}$ be the vector space of all functions from $\{1,2\}\rightarrow \textbf{F}$

Show that $\textbf{F}^{\{1,2\}}$ has a basis $f,g$ where

$f:\{1,2\}\rightarrow \textbf{F},f(1)=1,f(2)=0$

$g:\{1,2\}\rightarrow \textbf{F},g(1)=0,g(2)=1$

Attempt

Proving linear independence

$af(t)+bg(t)=0$ which holds for all $t \in \{1,2\}$

This gives the system of equations

$af(1)+bg(1)=0$

$af(2)+bg(2)=0$

$\implies a=b=0$

So $f,g$ are linearly independent.

Now prove span. I am not sure how to prove $f,g$ span $\textbf{F}^{\{1,2\}}$ any ideas?

Also is my approach for proving linear independence correct?

Comment: If $h\in\mathbf{F}^{\{1,2\}}$, then $h(x)=h(1)f(x)+h(2)g(x)$.

Comment: @flan I am a bit confused at your answer. Can you please explain a little further why that shows $f,g$ span $\textbf{F}^{\{1,2\}}$?

Comment: It is any $h$ written as a linear combination of your $f$ and $g$. So, linear combinations of $f$ and $g$ can produce all elements of $\mathbf{F}^{\{1,2\}}$.

Comment: Thanks, was linear independence proved the correct way?

Comment: Yes. It is fine.

Answer (score 1):

An intuitive way to look at this is to note that $\mathbb{F}^{\{1,2\}} \cong \mathbb{F}^2$ (vector of length 2 with entries in $\mathbb{F}$)

So for $h \in \mathbb{F}^{\{1,2\}}$, we can identify this with $(h(1), h(2)) \in \mathbb{F}^2 $

It's clear then that your $f$ and $g$ are the standard basis $(1,0), (0,1)$

and to see flan's commented answer (let $h_1=h(1)$, and $h_2 = h(2)$):

$h(t) \rightarrow (h_1, h_2) = h_1(1,0) + h_2(0,1) \rightarrow h_1f(t) + h_2g(t) = h(1)f(t) + h(2)g(t)$

In general, one way to think about vectors is as functions from the indices $\{1,...,n\}$ to $\mathbb{F}$

Comment: Thanks, I was also asked to prove the isomorphism. I think I have it done, but I was going to post a verification on doing that soon. To do that I would have to set up a linear map between the two vector spaces, and show it is invertible,correct?